# Add onSelectionChanged to WebView extended class

Tags: android, webview

As you know [`onSelectionChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onSelectionChanged%28int,%20int%29) is one of the `TextView` class function is called when `the selection has changed, in case any subclasses would like to know.`. I want to add it to the class that extends from `WebView`.

What should I do ? 
Could you please give me some help about how can I do ?

Comment: why exactly do you want to do this? Using something that's meant for something else is not recommended.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I would need something like this right now